# Proving the Archimedean Properties of Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

1) If $n, m\in\mathbb{Q}$ where $ n, m > 0$  then $\exists$ a positive integer $l$ s.t. $nl > m$.

2) For each positive integer $r$, there exists a rational number $c$, s.t. $c > r.$

3) For each $ y \in\mathbb{Q}, \exists n \in\mathbb{Z}$  $ s.t.$ $n \leqslant y < n+1$

4) For each positive rational number $m$ then $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z}$, c >$ 0$, s.t. $1/c < m$

I'm supposed to prove each of these without using the completeness axioms using direct proof but I have no idea what to do. For the first, would I just use the definition of rationals and then say that if we add l copies of n, eventually it would be bigger than m so ln > m?

Comment: Since n is not 0, m/n is a rational number.  So as long as there exist an integer, l, greater than m/n, it follows that ln> m.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take $l=2m$, so that $nl\ge 2m =m+m>m$ since $m>0$ and $n>0\iff n\ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback! I think I have 4) as well but 2) and 3) are still stumping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, write $n=a/b$ and $m=c/d$, with $a,b,c,d>0$. The integer $l$ should satisfy
$$
l\,\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
lad>bc
$$
By the division algorithm in the integers, you can write $bc=qad+r$, with $0\le r<ad$. In particular, $bc=qad+r<qad+ad=(q+1)ad$. Take $l=q+1$.

For 2, take $c=r+1$.

For 3, it's again the division algorithm: write $y=a/b$, with $b>0$. Then $a=bn+r$, with $0\le r<n$, so $bn\le a<bn+b=b(n+1)$ and therefore
$$
n\le \frac{a}{b}<n+1
$$

For 4, use 2: there exists a positive integer $c$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<c$ which is the same as $\frac{1}{c}<m$.

Answer (score 2):

1) This is equivalent to proving that there exists a natural number l such that $l > x$ for all $x$. After proving this just take $x = m/n$.
Suppose that for some specific $x$, $l ≤ x$ for all $l$. Then, $x$ is an upper bound for the natural numbers, which is impossible.

2) You can take $c = 2r > r$.

3) Consider the set of natural numbers greater than $|y|$. This is nonempty because of (1). Therefore the set is well ordered, and it has a minimum, we shall call it $N$. $N - 1$ is smaller than $N$ and therefore not in the set, so N - 1 ≤ |y| < N, now check both cases $y ≥ 0$ and $y < 0$.

4) $1/c < m$ iff $1 < mc$, but you proved that the existence of $c$ is guaranteed in item (1).